# how to remove unnecessary links on addition of google tag manager and tracking code

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-tag-manager

In wordpress [live site](http://www.lotustravel.se/) on addition of google tag manager and tracking code I am getting unnecessary redirects as http://adsby.bidtheatre.com and https://cm.g.doubleclick.net as seen in [tools.pingdom.com](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/eKku1f/http://lotustravel.se/). But whenever I comment google tag manager and tracking code those redirects aren't seen as in [tools.pingdom.com](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/eJaytQ/http://109.74.4.178/lotustravel/) dev server. I need those tag manager and tracking code but these are slowing down the speed.
How am I supposed to remove those redirects.
Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that removing this redirects will slightly improve the speed?

Comment: @mrbubu ... I tested the speed by commenting those js and I found the increase in speed but as I found in http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-and-setup-google-tag-manager-in-wordpress/ : in setup of tag manager you can add those tags as crazy egg, addsby. Now I am looking for tracking code via tb.de17a.com/d7.js